# Golang: Json from URL as map

Tags: json, rest, go

What is the best way to extract json from a url i.e. Rest service from Go?
Also it seems most rest client libraries in go force a use of the json.marshall which needs a struct to be used with it.

This doesn't work in the case of unstructured data where you don't fully know what will be coming in.  Is there a way to have it all simply come in as a map[string:string]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not to parse it into map[string]string as this code have to do

```
var d map[string]interface{}
data, err := json.Unmarshal(apiResponse, &d)
```

You can traverse data in this struct too.

If you suspect, that api response can be not singular object, but the collection of objects, the `interface{}` also works for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know what's coming in a message, you can have several situations.

## Message contents that depend on type

Type is usually indicated by some type field. In this case you can use a "union" struct that contains fields from all types:

```
type Foo struct {
    A int
    B string
}

type Bar struct {
    C int
    D string
}

type Message struct {
    Type string
    Foo
    Bar
}

// or this, if you have common fields

type Message struct {
    Type string
    A int
    B string
    C int
    D string
}
```

Unmarshal the message into the union struct, dispatch on type, and select the sub-struct.

```
var m Message
json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
switch m.Type {
    case "foo":
        ...
    case "bar":
        ...
}
```

## Completely dynamic messages

In this case you have a collection of unrelated key-values and process  them individually.

Parse into a `map[string]interface{}`. The downside, of course, is that you have to cast each value and check its type dynamically. **Caveat:** `map[string]interface{}` will convert all numbers to floats, even integers, so you have cast them to `float64`.

You can also use `map[string]json.RawMessage`, if you do not want to parse values, only keys (`json.RawMessage` is a `[]byte`, and is preserved as is when unmarshaled).

## "Envelope" message with dynamic payload

For example:

```
{
    "type": "foo",
    "payload": {
        "key1": "value1"
    }
}

{
    "type": "bar",
    "payload": {
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": [1, 2]
    }
}
```

Use a struct with `json.RawMessage`.

```
type Message struct {
    Type string
    Payload json.RawMessage
}

type Foo struct {
    Key1 string
}

type Bar struct {
    Key2 string
    Key3 []int
}
```

Parse the envelope (payload will be preserved), then dispatch on type, and parse payload into a sub-struct.

```
var m Message
_ = json.Unmarshal(data, &m)
switch m.Type {
    case "foo":
        var payload Foo
        _ = json.Unmarshal(m.Payload, &payload)
        // do stuff
    case "bar":
        var payload Bar
        _ = json.Unmarshal(m.Payload, &payload)
        // do stuff
}
```